# Problems receiving data from DirectLine in webchat client

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I have a bot that is hosted on Azure. Normal interaction with the bot is fine when the bot can internally handle the requests. But if I need to fetch something from a DB (a mongodb in this case). It hangs for about 2 min and then I get a 500 from the DirectLine api with no additional information.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I tried to up the timeout on both the azure instance and the web client but still the same issue at 2 min